# Is Yun male or female?

Tags: only-sense-online

In Only Sense Online, the main character is male, but in game people keep mistaking him for being female.

Did the game actually turn him into a female character, or did he just get his features made more feminine?

This was the explanation from the LN, but it doesn't actually state whether or not the avatar was skewed towards being feminine or it was actually a female body:

> When you don’t modify your body after your figure is captured by camera, an automatic body correction is applied. Mainly it works in the direction of adding femininity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Volume 2, the prologue states that the machine identified Syun as a female.

Unless there was a translation error in the previous volume, this is the first time there is definitive evidence that Syun's avatar Yun is female in the game.

This occurs when Yun goes an NPC and gets referred to as a female. He then explains how it happened.

Answer (score 2):

The game changed him into a female character because he didn't modify his body when setting it up. The game automatically added a body correction. It's near the beginning of Chapter 1 if you want to find it.

Comment: I've edited my question with the relevant quote, which I think you're talking about. If it is, it still doesn't say whether or not the avatar is male or female.

Answer (score 0):

In Krytyk's translation of volume 8, in chapter 3 there's this:

> I said and walked towards the men's bath entrance marked with blue curtain.
>   『"——Entering prohibited. You do not have authority to enter."』
>   "Wha?!!"
>   "Hey hey, Missy. That's men's bath. The one beside it is for women."
>   Mikadzuchi pointed at the red curtain marking women's bath...
>   As if I'd enter women's bathh!! Heck! Why the hell can't I enter men's?! I'm a man!